# Bitbucket Pipelines - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitbucket-pipelines

### Am I missing build tools in my configuration file?

I'm trying to integrate Bitbucket Pipelines with a Ruby project.

I am unable to build native gem extensions. My C knowledge is limited. If anyone has experience with this input is appreciated. The build fails where trying to install `faraday`

```
Installing faraday 0.9.2
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
Makefile:241: recipe for target 'fast.o' failed
make: *** [fast.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

My `bitbucket-piplines.yml` looks like

```
image: ruby:2.4.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - bundler
        script:
          - echo $PRIVATE_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp
          - base64 -d ~/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          - base64 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

          - gem install oj -v '2.9.9'
          - gem install faraday -v '0.9.2'
          - bundle config git.allow_insecure true
          - bundle install
          - bundle exec rspec

definitions:
  caches:
    bundler: ./vendor
```

Comment: Did you try `gem install faraday -v '0.9.2'` seperately...

Answer (score 0):

So it was an issue with my Ruby version. `Fixnum` is no longer a function in Ruby 2.4. It was a matter of downgrading the Ruby Docker image, or updating the failing gems. I downgraded while I'm getting my tests set up to `image: ruby:2.3.4`